# Interesting BC/Google Calculator Discrepancy

Tags: unix

Any reason to believe one vs the other is correct (other than ofcourse 13 is the correct answer)? See attached screenshot. I'd love to hear if this is reproducible or not. Link to picture is below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuBUv.png

Comment: Wolfram Alpha agrees with Google: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28golden+number%29%5E7%2Fsqrt%285%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want fractions to show up in the results of divisions in `bc`, you need to set `scale` to something other than `1`, the default.

```
(1.61803399^7)/sqrt(5)
14
scale=10
(1.61803399^7)/sqrt(5)
12.9845972055
```